# How can use hashmap to count the dice eye frequency?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class Count {
private static final int SIZE = 6;
private static int[] freq;
private static int i;

public static Map<Integer, Integer> count() {
    int[] freq = new int[SIZE];
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        ++freq[(int) (Math.random() * SIZE)];
    }
    return null;
}

public static void write(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        System.out.println("Dice eye = " + (i + 1) + ", Frequency = " + freq[i]);
}
}

public class Dice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = Count.count();
    Count.write(map);
}
}
```

I want to print out the frequency of dice eyes when I throw the dice 100 times using Hashmap.
I know how to make a Count class, but I don't know how to organize the method.
How to return the hashmap and save it?

```
An example of the output I want,
ex)
Dice eye = 1, Frequency = 15
Dice eye = 2, Frequency = 16
Dice eye = 3, Frequency = 12
Dice eye = 4, Frequency = 16
Dice eye = 5, Frequency = 25
Dice eye = 6, Frequency = 16
```

Comment: can you be more specific. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I've edited the post. The output I want is as above.

Comment: HINT:  the "dice eye" values will be the `Integer` map **keys**, the associated `Integer` values will be the frequency counts.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Create a method which converts yours freq array to HashMap

```
public static Map<Integer,Integer> Array_To_HashMap(){
    Map<Integer,Integer> map= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        map.put(i+1,freq[i]);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Call this in count function.
Your count class will look like this

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> count() {
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ++freq[(int) (Math.random() * SIZE)];
        }
        return Array_To_HashMap();
    }
```

EDIT:-

```
class Count {
    private static final int SIZE = 6;
    private static int[] freq=new int[SIZE];
    private static int i;

    public static Map<Integer, Integer> count() {
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ++freq[(int) (Math.random() * SIZE)];
        }
        return Array_To_HashMap();
    }

    public static Map<Integer,Integer> Array_To_HashMap(){
        Map<Integer,Integer> map= new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
            map.put(i+1,freq[i]);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void write(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
        map.forEach((eye,frequency)->{
            System.out.println("Dice eye = " + eye + ", Frequency = " + frequency);
        });
        }
}

public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = Count.count();
        Count.write(map);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but error occurs. 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: private static int[] freq=new int[SIZE];   in above declaration on  freq  and also if you notice there is difference between your count method and mine

Comment: yeah, I delete my count method and insert yours. The error occurred after that.